# Detailed 500 error message not showing, even on server

Tags: asp.net, iis, error-handling

I have a problem..

I migrated my website to amazon EC2, with windows server 2016 and IIS 10. 
Since this time, I cannot see detailed 500 error messages, even if I'm on the server.

I tried Error Pages -> 500 -> Edit Feature Settings -> "Detailed Error", on both my website and the topmost node of IIS..

I still have the message: 'An error has occurred.' from my asp.net web service, instead of the detailed message.

I migrated 4 websites, and they all have this problem. On the old server, with the same web.config all work fine..

Anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, for asp.net 500 error, you should enable the custom error in the web.config instead of using the IIS error page.

The IIS error page(httpErrors attribute in web.config) is used when IIS itself is throwing an exception.

But the customErrors attribute is used when the .net code is throwing an exception (404, 403, 500 etc).

You shouldchange the  tag inside the  section as below:

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
 <system.web>
```

Comment: I already have 
 <system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off" />
  <compilation debug="true" />
 </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
 <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" /><
  </system.webServer>

Comment: Do you have some speical setting in your asp.net application? Like set error handle codes in the global.asax's Application_Error method? Besides,I suggest you could try to connect to the  amazon EC2  windows server's event viewer to see the details error message.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but errors of the asp.net webservice are not logged into the windows events

Comment: 500 error means inernal serve error, it is so strange that there are no details error message. I suggest you could try to use  WCF tracing to see the details error message firstly.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing